# Populate NULL value with most recent value from the same column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to populate NULL values in a column with the most recent non-NULL value in that column. For instance in the example below I want the IG column for the FR and first SPR values to be '1', but the final SPR value to be '0'.

As I am attempting to track changes in the IG variable over time for a given issue_ID I need this to make sure I do not populate NULL values for one issue_ID with results from another issue_ID.

I have been able to update the NULL values with the following code. The problem is that this is unable to identify the **last** non-NULL value. It appears to simply take the IG value for **any** non-NULL value that is before the row in question.

For instance for the row containing SPR and '2002-12-02' the IG variable is populated '1', rather than the desired '0'.

Any assistance would be **HUGELY** appreciated.

Example Code:

```
UPDATE ratings_base a
    SET ig =  b.ig
    FROM 
    (
     SELECT issue_id,
            rating,
            date,
            IG
    FROM ratings_base
    WHERE agency = 'MR' 
    ) b
WHERE a.rating IS NOT NULL
AND a.agency != 'MR'
AND b.date < a.date
AND a.issue_id = b.issue_id;
```

Example Data:

```
Issue_ID | Agency |    Date    | Rating | IG
---------------------------------------------
1        | MR     | 2002-05-29 |   8    | 1 
1        | MR     | 2002-08-14 |   8    | 1
1        | FR     | 2002-08-19 |   11   | NULL
1        | SPR    | 2002-09-23 |   9    | NULL
1        | MR     | 2002-10-02 |   9    | 1
1        | MR     | 2002-11-26 |   11   | 0
1        | SPR    | 2002-12-02 |   12   | NULL
2        | MR     | 2002-08-14 |   8    | 1
2        | MR     | 2002-08-17 |   8    | 1
```

Comment: `WHERE a.rating IS NOT NULL`, are you sure that `IS NULL` shouldn't be  here instead?

Comment: Hi Giorgi, apologies but in my full dataset there are some instances where the 'Rating' Variable in NULL (not shown in my example). It is not a typo in my code. I would probably also want to add a condition for where the 'IG' variable IS NULL though. Thanks

Comment: sorry, I thought it was IG compared to not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about moving the subquery into the `update`, and make sure to order if correctly to get the latest `ig` value:

```
UPDATE ratings_base a
SET ig = (
  SELECT b.ig
  FROM ratings_base b
  WHERE a.issue_id = b.issue_id
  AND b.agency = 'MR' 
  AND b.date < a.date
  ORDER BY b.date DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
WHERE a.rating IS NOT NULL
AND a.agency != 'MR';
```